# Yii2 Bootstrap assets not available when using custom layout in module

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, yii, yii2

**Context**

I have a Yii2 application in which there is a module for administration.

I would like to use a specific layout for this module thus, in the Admin.php for the module I declare

```
public $layout = 'main';
```

and place the specific layout in the wiews/layouts folder of the module

The layout for the application uses

```
AppAsset::register($this);
```

and so do the layout for the admin module.

The AppAsset.php is trivial

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';

    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [

        'scss/myOwnStyle.scss'
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',  
    ];
}
```

The functionality of Bootstrap I want to use is the tabbed view.

**Results**

Letting things as described above, the switching between tabs in an admin page doesn't work.
Removing the specif layout from admin module, everything works well.

In fact, this is due to the absence of the Bootstrap javascript in the page. Indeed

```
<script src="/assets/f7ad570a/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

do not appear in the source of the page when using the specific layout.

**My question**

How comes the bootstrap.js script is not included in the admin pages when using my specific layout ?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `yii2-bootstrap` does not load JavaScript files untill it's necessary. And it's necessary when you are using `yii2-bootstrap` widgets.

I'm guessing you are not calling `yii2-bootstrap` widget to generate Bootstrap component but rather generating it on your own.

In this case do what `yii2-bootstrap` is doing - register `yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset` as well.

Comment: Thank you for answer. You are right. I must investigate deeper. What I could make out is that I was using the Nav widget without putting it between Navbar:begin and Navbar:end. Since I reintroduced this Navbar things work fine and boostrap.js is reintroduced into the page.

Comment: But only registering BootstrapPluginAsset  works fine as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason why that happens, but try to put the javascript before the `<body>`, should we?

```
public $jsOptions = [
    'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD
];
```